# How would i go about putting a timer so someone wouldnt be able to spam it? (Lua)

Tags: lua, grand-theft-auto, fivem

I would like to add a timer to the following code (Lua)

```
CreateThread(function()

    while true do
        Wait(0)
           --if IsControlPressed(1, 47) then  --  G 
            local CitoyenCible, distance = getNearPlayer()
            if (distance ~= -1 and distance < 1.5001) then

                if IsPedArmed(GetPlayerPed(-1), 7) then
                    SetCurrentPedWeapon(GetPlayerPed(-1), GetHashKey('WEAPON_UNARMED'), true)
                end

                if (DoesEntityExist(GetPlayerPed(-1)) and not IsEntityDead(GetPlayerPed(-1))) then
                    ChargementAnimation("melee@unarmed@streamed_variations")
                    TaskPlayAnim(GetPlayerPed(-1), "melee@unarmed@streamed_variations", "plyr_takedown_front_slap", 8.0, 1.0, 1500, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
                    TriggerServerEvent("RebornProject:SyncGiffle", GetPlayerServerId(CitoyenCible))
                end
            else
                TriggerEvent("RebornProject:Notification", Notif1)
            end
        end
    end
end)
```

Comment: this is no native Lua, name the libraries you're using. Also it is not clear what you want to achive. how does someone spam a timer?

Comment: I dont know much about lua, its a script for slapping people in fivem. I'm not the one who wrote it, but i'd like to add a timer to avoid the function being spammed. I tried changing the wait value to see what would happend, but it just added a delay from the keypress to the function. I hope this made it a bit cleaer

Comment: @kaviwi, what you need is variable outside your loop, something like `lastPressTime` then you set it to `0` initially. now you can check if the press was some duration of time ago by doing `(os.time() - lastPressTime) > 3`, this would be 3 seconds. when the duration is acceptable be sure to `lastPressTime = os.time()`

Comment: Thanks @Nifim! I'll try that when i get the time

Answer (score 0):

Add a Variable outside of the Thread.
local Timer = 0

Then add another thread that will start the timer when the value is greater then 0.

Citizen.CreateThread(function()
    while true do
        Citizen.Wait(0)
        if Timer > 0 then
            Timer = Timer - 1
            Citizen.Wait(1000)
        end
    end
end)

Then just add the variable where you need it with a conditional statement and somewhere that sets the timer. You could utilize Citizen.Wait() if you want the thread to run over and over again but with a timer at the end so it doesn't restart immediately you can. Citizen.Wait(milliseconds).